# Как написать "&" символ в React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, link

[image: For example]

Как мне написать этот символ на React?

Comment: используй специальный символ &amp; вместо &

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй {} скобки:
url={"тут твой url"}

Comment: Спасибо, заработала. Как не странно, но когда я так писал, у меня всё равно ошибка выходила. А когда написал повторно ошибок нет. Как это работает - я не знаю.